# Maven Glassfish embedded server using jax-ws

Tags: java, maven, glassfish-embedded

I tried to biuld my first Maven project using embedded glassfish server to provide a jax-ws webservice and static page.

My problem at this time is that the glassfish server start and I have glassfish 404 page on http://localhost:8080 and on https://localhost:8181

You can find extra information of my project on https://github.com/BeRoots/WeathforcastWS2

If someone has an idea why my index.html not work and return a 404 ?

[EDIT] The documentation user to build this project is on https://glassfish.org/docs/latest/embedded-server-guide.pdf#gjldy

Comment: You can not easily test in Glassfish, at least the configuration part in pom xml is not really working, you are getting 404 because embedded server is not really deploying your war, you can run separate glassfish installation and manage it but it will not be easy, I suggest go use spring boot :)